# How does functions work with only one parentheses if linked to an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(function(num) {
  console.log(num);
});
```

How does this function works properly with `(function(num)` what I know it should be `(function(num))`

with an extra `)`

Comment: `.forEach(` <-- open - line 1 | close - line 3--> `);`

Comment: May you explain why you think that?

Comment: There are no extra braces in your example.

Comment: I can't understand what is written inside of the parentheses

Comment: @evolutionxbox The user is probably not aware how white space works and how expressions can be passed as parameters. He/She is just generally confused by the function expression as a parameter in this syntax case.

Comment: `function(num) { console.log(num); }` is passed inside `.forEach( <here> )`

Comment: @zero298 in my example `(function(num)` is the right one to use while `(function((num)` is what I thought to use

Comment: In your example, the forEach function is taking a anonymous callback function as its argument.

Comment: @evolutionxbox is there something I should search to learn what you are talking about?

Answer (score 4):

Hey Imagine that the function would be saved into the variable

```js
var someFunction = function(num) {
  console.log(num);
};
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(someFunction);
```

so you just passing function there as a parameter and then `forEach` as a function would call it inside itself, so it is not a call of this function, so doesn't need parenthesis.

Comment: @MarcoMaher this is a good answer and shows another way to write the code you gave. Functions can be passed around like other variables.